# AzureDevops stage dependsOn stageDependencies

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

How to create a multi-stage pipeline depending on a stage/job-name derived from a parameter whereas stages run firstly in parallel and eventually one stage that waits for all previous stages?

---

Here's what I've tried so far:
A multi-stage pipeline runs for several stages depending on a tool parameter in parallel, whereas `dependsOn` is passed as parameter. Running it in parallel for each tool waiting for the previous stage for the said tool works smoothly.

Main template: all wait for for all

```
- ${{ each tool in parameters.Tools }}:
  - template: ../stages/all-wait-for-all.yml
    parameters:
      Tool: ${{ tool }}
```

stages/all-wait-for-all.yml

```
parameters:
  - name: Tool
    type: string
stages:
  - stage: ALL_WAIT_${{ parameters.Tool}}
    dependsOn:
    - PREPARE_STAGE
    - OTHER_TEMPLATE_EXECUTED_FOR_ALL_TOOLS_${{ parameters.Tool }}
```

Now there should be one stage that should only run once and not per tool, but it should only run after the individual tool stages are done. It can't be hardcoded as there are various tools. So I hoped defining the individual wait-stages in a prepare job would work out:

Main template: prepare-stage

```
    - script: |
        toolJson=$(echo '${{ convertToJson(parameters.Tools) }}')
        tools=$(echo "$toolJson" | jq '.[]' | xargs)
        stage="ALL_WAIT"

        for tool in $tools; do
          stageName="${stage}_${tool }"
          stageWaitArray+=($stageName)
        done

        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=WAIT_ON_STAGES]${stageWaitArray}"
        echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=WAIT_ON_STAGES;isOutput=true]${stageWaitArray}"
      displayName: "Define wait stages"
      name: WaitStage
```

stages/one-waits-for-all.yml

```
stages:
  - stage: ONE_WAITS
    dependsOn:
    - $[ stageDependencies.PREPARE_STAGE.PREPARE_JOB.outputs['waitStage.WAIT_ON_STAGES'] ]
```

whereas below error is shown:
`Stage ONE_WAITS depends on unknown stage $[ stageDependencies.PREPARE_STAGE.PREPARE_JOB.outputs['WaitStage.WAIT_ON_STAGES'] ].`

Comment: Dependencies need to be declared before execution starts. You may be able to generate the dependson using a template that uses the decorator syntax... And use iterative insertion... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#iterative-insertion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess I was overthinking the solution as eventually it was pretty obvious.

So first template can be called within a loop from the main template whereas it's executed as many times as tools we got. Second template shall be called once waiting on previous stages for all tools, whereas the job/stage prefix is known, only the tool name as postfix was unknown. So just add them in a loop directly in `dependsOn`..

Here you go:

```
stages:
  - stage: ONE_WAITS
    dependsOn:
    - PREPARE_STAGE
    - ${{ each tool in parameters.Tools }}:
      - OTHER_TEMPLATE_EXECUTED_FOR_ALL_TOOLS_${{ tool}}
      - ALL_WAIT_${{ tool }}
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand depends on can not have dynamic $[] or macro $() expressions  evaluated at runtime. You can use template expressions ${{}} which are evaluated at queue time.